# Serialize object into XML including "xsi:schemaLocation" and order of attributes

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have this class

```
public class EnvioDTE
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string version { get; set; }

    public EnvioDTE()
    {
        this.version = "1.0";
    }
}
```

I am serializing it to XML with the following code:

```
EnvioDTE envioDTE = new EnvioDTE();

string xml = "";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EnvioDTE));
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    NewLineChars = "\n",
    OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
    Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
};

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
        xml = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

Which is giving me the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<EnvioDTE version="1.0">
</EnvioDTE>
```

**What do I need to add to my code so that I get the following attributes?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<EnvioDTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd" version="1.0">
</EnvioDTE>
```

**The order of the attributes is important for me.**

I tried by making two changes:

**Change #1**

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte")] // *** NEW
public class EnvioDTE
{
    [XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")] // *** NEW
    public string schemaLocation { get; set; } // *** NEW
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string version { get; set; }

    public EnvioDTE()
    {
        this.version = "1.0";
    }
}
```

**Change #2**

```
EnvioDTE envioDTE = new EnvioDTE();

string xml = "";

var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(); // *** NEW
namespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"); // *** NEW

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EnvioDTE));
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    NewLineChars = "\n",
    OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
    Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
};

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, this, namespaces); // *** NEW
        xml = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

With those changes I'm getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<EnvioDTE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte">
</EnvioDTE>
```

And that is not the order of attributes I want...

Comment: According to [xml-specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags): Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.

Comment: hm ok... but I will be signing this document. It could be relevant in that scenario (not sure tho, because the part to be signed is a node within the xml)

Comment: The order of elements in XML is significant.  There is no ordering of attributes.  Now there is a non-normative canonical form that says that attributes are ordered by name, and I expect that serializer follows that ordering (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML).  Does it in your case?

Answer (score 0):

So you are just trying to read out the XML? I would do this:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (reader != null)
{                           
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sb.AppendLine(reader.ReadOuterXml());
    }
    doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(Convert.ToString(sb));

    XmlNodeList xmlNodeList;

    xmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Whatever your tag name");

    for (i = 0; i < xmlNodeList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (xmlNodeList[i].InnerXml.Length > 0)
        {
            foo = xmlNodeList[i].InnerXml;
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, you are just trying to output? Then do this. I know it's a bit of a hack and there is probably a million ways to do it:

```
string myXMLstring = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding="iso-8859-1\"?>" +
<EnvioDTE xmlns=\"http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte\"" + 
xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
"xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd\"" + 
"version=\"1.0\">" +
"</EnvioDTE>";
```

I've escaped the the quotes and built it up as a string. You can even add \r\n anytime you know you need a new line. I hope that helps. Happy coding!

Comment: I'm not trying to read the xml, from where in my question did you conclude that?